# How do I split each line in the file into three variables and then print it?

Tags: python

After writing a 'who' command and redirecting it into the users.txt file, I need to break up each line of the text into three variables: who, where, and when_and_IP. And print the output.

```
who > users.txt

file = open("users.txt", "w")


users = file.split("who", "where", "when").rstrip("\n")

for user in users:
    if file.startswith("who"):
        print(file.startswith("who") + file.startswith("where") + file.startswith(when_and_IP))
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code?

Comment: what's wrong with your output? post both your current output and expected output.

Comment: `file` is a file, it doesn't  have a `split` method (or a `startswith` method). Strings have those methods. Start simple: can you successfully open the file, read lines from it, and print them out? Get that working first, and show us the resulting code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues with your code:

- You're opening the file in write mode by passing the `"w"` argument, which will actually erase the file's contents. Use `"r"` for reading, or don't specify the mode at all as `"r"` is the defaut.
- `file` doesn't has a `split` method, you need to iterate it to operate on the lines, then probably split them.
- `split`'s argument should be the separator by which you want to split. If you don't pass any argument then it will split by any whitespace character (space, tab, newline) which is probably what you want here.
- `startswith` is not a method of `file`, it is a method of string and it returns a boolean (`True` or `False`) telling whether the string starts with the substring. So it doesn't seem to make sense to use it here.

Here's some working example that might help you achieve your goal:

```py
>>> users = open("users.txt").readlines()
>>> users = [line.rstrip().split(maxsplit=2) for line in users]
>>> users
[['user1', 'tty7', '2020-10-31 00:12 (:0)'], ['user2', 'tty2', '2020-11-07 14:43']]
>>> for who, where, when in users:
...     print(f"who={who}, where={where}, when={when}")
who=user1, where=tty7, when=2020-10-31 00:12 (:0)
who=user2, where=tty2, when=2020-11-07 14:43
```